# Remove clock from top bar in Ubuntu 19.10 Mate

Tags: gnome, 19.10, mate, ubuntu-mate, clock

I deactivated the clock in the right top bar in Ubuntu 18.04 Mate and updates few days ago to Ubuntu 19.10. The clock reappears and - for the heck - there ist no option to remove it.

Where can I remove only the clock in the top bar in Ubuntu 19.10?

**Update to the questions:**

I didn't change the desktop, so I think it's the standard MATE desktop.

The output of `export | grep DESKTOP ; gsettings get org.mate.panel default-layout`:

```
declare -x DESKTOP_SESSION="mate"
declare -x MATE_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID="this-is-deprecated"
declare -x XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP="MATE" 
declare -x XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP="mate"
'familiar'
```

Comment: Are you running MATE desktop in the 19.10? What panel layout do you have? Please add output of `export | grep DESKTOP ; gsettings get  org.mate.panel default-layout` to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert I added the informations above.